# Changing density() parameter 'adjust' in R results in an area under the density curve of significantly greater than 1

Tags: r

[density() Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/density)

[trapz() Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/trapz)

My understanding of is that the area under the curve of a density is 1 by definition, otherwise it's not actually a density.

I was writing code to create a GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model) with some constraints and wanted to compare the output to a density model. I'm working with data with a lot of components, some of which have very narrow standard deviations. The density() function default looked like it was oversmoothing the density of my empirical data some, so I decided to lower the bandwidth. density() includes a parameter, 'adjust', which the documentation states is the coefficient on the bandwidth of the kernels in density(). I dropped the value to 0.1 and then continued to build my modeling code. When it came time to test the model, it looked like it was failing to rise to the peak in the data. After quite a while of looking for bugs in my code (there weren't any obvious ones after hours of inspection and fixing) and rewriting the algorithm and getting the same result, I tested the area under the model curve I'd generated. It was 1, but visually far below the curve generated by `density(x = x, adjust = 0.1)`. So I decided to test the area under the curve of the density() outputs. 6.28 for my data. I was pretty surprised by this--I had immediately dismissed the idea that the AUC of the density() function was anything other than 1.

This effect replicates with a simple mixture on my computer. First, an example showing that the AUC for a sample density is ~1 with the adjust parameter at 1.

```
require(stats)
require(pracma)
set.seed(1)
gaussianMix <- c(rnorm(n = 5000, 
                       mean = -50, 
                       sd = 50), 
                 rnorm(n = 100000, 
                       mean = 0, 
                       sd = 10),
                 rnorm(n = 10000,
                       mean = 50,
                       sd = 100)
                 )

mixtureDensity <- density(x = gaussianMix,
                          adjust = 1)

plot(mixtureDensity)

area <- trapz(mixtureDensity$x,
              mixtureDensity$y)
area

1.001025
```

Now with and adjust parameter of 0.1

```
require(stats)
require(pracma)
set.seed(1)
gaussianMix <- c(rnorm(n = 5000, 
                       mean = -50, 
                       sd = 50), 
                 rnorm(n = 100000, 
                       mean = 0, 
                       sd = 10),
                 rnorm(n = 10000,
                       mean = 50,
                       sd = 100)
                 )

mixtureDensity <- density(x = gaussianMix,
                          adjust = 0.1)

plot(mixtureDensity)

area <- trapz(mixtureDensity$x,
              mixtureDensity$y)
area

5.655676
```

Am I missing something obvious? Why is the bandwidth adjust coefficient causing an AUC of much greater than 1? It's easy enough to account for this by dividing the output of density()$y by the calculated area under the curve, but it was very jarring to realize that I was looking at a "density" curve with an AUC of more than 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something, though maybe it's not obvious. Look at the density plot:  it is very angular, not smooth at all.  You are not evaluating it at enough points.  If you add `n = 16384` to your `density()` call, you'll evaluate it at 32 times as many points, and the area estimate will come out close to 1.

```
mixtureDensity <- density(x = gaussianMix,
                          adjust = 0.1, n = 16384)

trapz(mixtureDensity$x, mixtureDensity$y)

# [1] 1.00003
```

Edited to add:  I was thinking it was just integration error causing the trouble, but it actually appears to be more than that.  Here I have superimposed 3 density estimates, with `n = 512` (the default, in black), `n = 1024` (blue), and `n = 16384` (red):

[image]

Bigger values of `n` reproduce the red one.  So in fact it looks as though the density estimates are wrong, it's not just badly discretized.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looked like to me. Seems like a reportable bug, no?

Comment: Yes, a bug report seems in order.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the Fourier transform of the kernel is inaccurate when `n=512`.  The code doesn't allow `n` to be set any smaller; that's probably based on bad behaviour for `adjust = 1`.  It might make sense to require `n >= 512/adjust` instead.